# How to start communication between pi and GSM add-on V2.0

Tags: pi-2, serial, gsm

I have mounted on the GSM add-on v2.0(sim 800) on the pi. I have read the AT commands manual but don't know how to initialize the serial connection between both of them till the point AT commands have to be entered. I can't find any information online. Any information will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To initiate GPRS transmission you will need to use PPTP software, over the serial connection. Like an old modem, read up about that.(The phone number is *9***1) To do fancy things, like signal triangulation, sending SMS and maybe even placing calls, then you use the AT commands, over serial. You can use `screen` but wire up like John La Rooy suggests, using the hardware serial pins.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a recent version of `raspi-config`, you will find there is an option to prevent taking over the serial port as a console.

Then it is free for you to use as a regular serial port

https://www.cube-controls.com/2015/11/02/disable-serial-port-terminal-output-on-raspbian/